# How to disable font aliasing in freebsd?

Tags: fonts, xorg, freebsd

I'd like to disable font aliasing at all. It looks ugly on my lcd screen. I tried to google but configuration various from distro to distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the section 6.5.3 in the handbook?

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-fonts.html

Comment: no word "disable" found in that link =)

Comment: well there is an example how to disable aliasing for some font sizes or some fonts. You should be able to adapt it to disable it for all fonts. If you need a text with "disable", the same examples can be found in the wikipedia article on fontconfig and the fontconfig documentation http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/fonts2.html